# Scala/Spark: Checking for null elements in an array column but IntelliJ suggests not to use null?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a column called `responseTimes` which is of arrayType:

```
ArrayType(IntegerType,true)
```

I'm trying to add another column to count the number of `null` or not-set values in this array:

```
val contains_null = udf((xs: Seq[Integer]) => xs.contains(null))
df.withColumn("totalNulls", when(contains_null(col("responseTimes")),
    lit(1)).otherwise(0))
```

Although this gives me the right output, IntelliJ keeps telling me to avoid the use of `null` in my UDF which makes me think this is bad. Is there any other way to do it? Also, is it possible without using UDFs?

Comment: I've done exactly what is mentioned in the above link. I'm looking for an alternative to avoid using "null" in the UDF

Answer (score 0):

The reason is very simple , it is because of the rules of spark udf, well spark deals with null in a different distributed way, I don't know if you know the array_contains built-in function in spark sql.

If UDFs are needed, follow these rules:

1. Scala code should deal with null values gracefully and shouldn’t error out if there are null values.
2. Scala code should return None (or null) for values that are unknown, missing, or irrelevant. DataFrames should also use null for for values that are unknown, missing, or irrelevant.
3. Use Option in Scala code and fall back on null if Option becomes a performance bottleneck.

Please refer to this link if you like tp read more: https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/dealing-with-null/

Comment: array_contains function cannot take in a NULL value. I get the error "cannot resolve 'array_contains(`responseTimes`, NULL)' due to data type mismatch: Null typed values cannot be used as arguments;;)

Comment: Array_contains takes a column and a value as parameters

Comment: Right. Can you please add how I can use array_contains to check of it contains null values?

Comment: `array_contains` will not work for null values as you can't check null equality

Comment: You can adapt your Udf by using contains with options by referring to the second point in the udf rules ( use None and son on )

Answer (score 0):

A better way is probably to use higher order function `exists` to check `isnull` for each array element:

```
// sample dataframe
val df = spark.sql("select array(1,null,2) responseTimes union all select array(3,4)")

df.show
+-------------+
|responseTimes|
+-------------+
|      [1,, 2]|
|       [3, 4]|
+-------------+

// check whether there exists null elements in the array
val df2 = df.withColumn("totalNulls", expr("int(exists(responseTimes, x -> isnull(x)))"))

df2.show
+-------------+----------+
|responseTimes|totalNulls|
+-------------+----------+
|      [1,, 2]|         1|
|       [3, 4]|         0|
+-------------+----------+
```

You can also use `array_max` together with `transform`:

```
val df2 = df.withColumn("totalNulls", expr("int(array_max(transform(responseTimes, x -> isnull(x))))"))

df2.show
+-------------+----------+
|responseTimes|totalNulls|
+-------------+----------+
|      [1,, 2]|         1|
|       [3, 4]|         0|
+-------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite your UDF to use `Option`. In scala, `Option(null)` gives `None`, so you can do :

```scala
val contains_null = udf((xs: Seq[Integer]) => xs.exists(e => Option(e).isEmpty))
```

However, if you are using Spark 2.4+, it is more suitable to use Spark built-in functions for this. To check if an array column contains null elements, use [`exists`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/#exists) as suggested by @mck's answer.

If you want to get the count of nulls in array you can combine `filter` and `size` function :

```scala
df.withColumn("totalNulls", size(expr("filter(responseTimes, x -> x is null)")))
```